# How to add color to the disabled window when pop up is arrised in the below block?

Tags: jquery

How to add color to the disabled window when pop up arises in the below block?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#hello" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,  
        modal:true,
    });
});
```

Comment: Can show us what you have worked on?

Comment: I have a registration form ..static display of all the html tags are in html file and the validation part is in .js file...im including js file to html file and validating the form...after validation i have to display the information which i have entered in the form in a popup..so i have to disable the parent window r8 so how can i disable the parent window completely gtng gray color and nly pop up window should be displayed

Comment: Can you please add your code in the fiddle. Because I am seeing blank fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nagabhavani/9L0y2uLy/
dats the code...analyse...

Comment: You need to add all required tags in fiddle. Because I am unable to get you pop up after submitting the form.

Comment: provide me your updated link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nagabhavani/9L0y2uLy/7/

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a class to the `body-container` element when the new window has been clicked.

In your stylesheet you give that class some `background-color` and when you click the `#hello div` you can use `$.addClass` to the container element like so:

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link hope that works with you.

http://jsfiddle.net/9L0y2uLy/9/

```
$(".hide").css("opacity", "0");
```

Comment: But the whole content of the parent is vanished even after closing the pop up....i request to get a grey color when pop is arrised ...i should not have a chance to click on any button or anthng